# Import DataBase from another app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am learning content provider. Now I can get the data base values from one app to another app using of Content provider. Now I want to get entire database from one app to another app.

Now my try is get the value form A app and store that in B app. But the problem is A app having more than 100 tables. So that I decided to get the entire database from A app to B app. Is it possible to get the database from A app  and import to B app?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

On an un-rooted device? No (sandbox). From the application level? No (sandbox again). From adb on an rooted device? Yes.

Any usecase that might need to utilize such functionality? I highly doubt it. Well, maybe if one lost his signing key and tries to rescue the live data from the old app within the new one. Or just trying to be evil by stealing data for blackmailing purposes.

But even if you manage the database, sometimes ContentProviders are more then just a layer around the database (see ContactProvider for example). So even if you have the tables they might be useless unless you also have the provider logic.